# php findall not displaying the content of my DB

Tags: php, crud, findall

first question here, because i'm stuck since this morning and i don't find a single way to fix my problem.

I'm trying to show every images listed in my DB (DB contains img name, img are stored in local files, each has been send in the same time via an input page).

The current code do not send any errors between thoses parts :

```
    public function findall()
    {
        require_once ('Classes/ClasseDB.php');

        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $req = "SELECT IDphoto, nomImage, testCom FROM test";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($req);
        $CollectionPhotos = array();
        while ($ligne = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $LaPhoto = new ClasseTest($ligne["testCom"]);
            array_push($CollectionPhotos, $LaPhoto);
        }
        return $CollectionPhotos;
    }

    public function get_nomImage()
    {
        return $this->nomImage;
    }
```

And

```
Image List :

<?php
echo "test1 ";
require_once "Classes/ClasseTest.php";
$laPhoto = new ClasseTest;
$CollectionPhotos = $laPhoto -> findall();
$i = 0;
echo "test2 ";
while ($i < count($CollectionPhotos)){

// here is where it's broken ↓
    echo $CollectionPhotos[$i]->get_nomImage(); //don't work :'(
//html <img __ > is removed in order to simplify      
    
    echo 'test3 '; //shows every items
    $i++;
}
echo "test4 ";
?>
```

ClasseDB code here as asked :

```
<?php

class Database {
    public static $conn = null;
    public static function connect() {
        if ( null == self::$conn ) {
            try {
                self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', '');
                self::$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return self::$conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Each tests are shown, and 'test3' appears 10 times, so i know my loop repeats enough times.

Nb : this is like what we did in class...

So what is wronnnng, is that a newbie mistake, a misspelling or a bug (my pc has done everything to me so that's also possible) ?

Comment: please give us your code for the `Database` class.

Comment: While this won't fix your issue, it's a bit more readable to do `foreach($CollectionPhotos as $photo)` instead of using a while loop to get the array key. If you need `$i` for something other than the array key, then you can use `foreach($CollectionPhotos as $i => $photo)`

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the new code, as code in comments is unreadable

Comment: So i guess instead of "while" it would be something like : `foreach(---) { echo $photo }`

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, you select three columns:

```sql
SELECT IDphoto, nomImage, testCom FROM test
```

However, only one of these is actually referenced in your PHP code:

```php
$LaPhoto = new ClasseTest($ligne["testCom"]);
```

You haven't shown the [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of `ClasseTest`, so it's not clear where `testCom` is stored (if anywhere), but from its name, I suspect it is *not* in the `nomImage` property, which is what you later try to retrieve:

```php
public function get_nomImage()
{
    return $this->nomImage;
}
```

That property is presumably supposed to come from the `nomImage` column in the database, which you're not storing anywhere.

You can help yourself a lot by naming things more carefully and thinking about *responsibilities*. If you want an object representing a photo, the logical name for it would be `Photo`, and you would pass *all* the columns you've selected to its constructor:

```php
$LaPhoto = new Photo($ligne["IDphoto"], $ligne["nomImage"], $ligne["testCom"]);
```

Your `findAll` method doesn't belong to a *single photo*, so you can either put it on a different class, like `ChercheurPhoto`:

```php
$leChercheurPhoto = new ChercheurPhoto;
$CollectionPhotos = $leChercheurPhoto->findall();
```

Or, you can use a [static method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), which is a method on the class, not a particular *instance* of the class:

```php
$CollectionPhotos = Photo::findall();
```

Comment: ah yep, about testCom, as it's named, it was only a test, i was looking to pass the image file/name and a commentary in a single form, as my final goal is to do a kind of showcase website.
Also,  as you probably figured, IDphoto is automaticaly incremented in db

Comment: @Qwatzyll What the _other_ columns are is not really relevant to what I wrote. The reason `nomImage` is not available in your PHP code, is because you haven't put it anywhere.

Comment: I tried to rename my objet as 'photo' as you advised me and it worked, even if everything was correct before (intelij AI + double check), concerning the 'ChercheurPhoto' part, i don't really understand who it works...

Comment: @Qwatzyll The point with the "ChercheurPhoto" example is that your "findAll" method doesn't belong to a single photo, so doesn't need to be on the same "Photo" class. If you're looking for photos of your aunt, you don't start by picking up a blank photo, you pick up a photo album, or open a drawer where you keep your photos; in the same way, it doesn't make sense to write "new Photo" in order to _search_ for photos in your database.